# Iteration limit reached (too few observations in a category?)

Tags: matlab, iteration, logistic-regression, categorical-data

in order to identify important variables in a dataset, I am starting out with making a univariate logistic regression model for each of the variables. However, for some categorical variables, there are only a few observations in some categories (the total number of observations is 1155; there are no missing values). Running the code

```
modelspec1='Y ~ X';
B1 = fitglm(table,modelspec1,'Distribution','binomial');
```

returns the error

```
Warning: Iteration limit reached. 
In glmfit (line 324)
In GeneralizedLinearModel/fitter (line 575)
In classreg.regr.FitObject/doFit (line 94)
In GeneralizedLinearModel.fit (line 882)
In fitglm (line 142)
```

and the estimate of beta becomes around 100, with a huge standard error and a p-value close to 1. I have tried to increase the number of iterations using

```
opts = statset('glmfit');
opts.MaxIter = 10000; % default value for glmfit is 100.
```

but it did not help. I really need to get some kind of an estimate (just dropping a category is sadly not an option). How can I fix the problem?

Comment: There is no error in your question, just a warning

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong word. However, I get no reasonable estimation of the beta, which I really need (maybe I should mention that I am also implementing an already existing model for which I get the same warning - verified by peer review and in practice, so I really need some kind of a valid estimation for my sample).

Comment: we cant really say because there is no [mcve], you may have bad data as far as we know

Comment: What do you mean by bad data? It may be, but it's what I have. I am not allowed to share it, however, as an example (there are more such examples with the same warning): a dummy variable where 0 occurs 1132 times, and 1 occurs only 23 times. How can I get an estimate for its beta?

Comment: Please edit that into your question, so that we can copy-paste and see what you are seeing. Thanks!